# SSIS Other Destinations and Sources are missing

Tags: ssis, ole

I am trying to learn SSIS and came across this problem where I wanted to add OLE Destination and Source.

My SSIS Toolbox is missing lots of stuff, and when I right click I don't get the choose item option (showing at the bottom of the screenshot)

If I go to the normal Toolbox Menu and right click and choose item, the choose item dialog doesn't have option to add SSIS items.
What is wrong? Can you help please?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place. The screenshot shows the Control Flow. These are Tasks.

There is a special design surface for a Task called "Data Flow Task." Add one of those to the Control Flow and then you'll be able to access OLE DB Source?/Destination, etc.